# split first part of string in every index of array and retain the rest of the string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Below is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] =>  2016-03-31 abc xyz  
[1] =>  2016-03-31 ef yz    
[2] =>  2016-04-05 ghij aei 
)
```

I need to remove the date from all the indexes in the above array and retain only the rest of the string.

Expected output:

```
Array
(
[0] =>  abc xyz 
[1] =>  ef yz   
[2] =>  ghij aei    
)
```

Thanks,
Madhuri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do, if the dates always come first and are in the same format (10 symbols):

```
foreach ($array as &$v) {$v = trim(substr($v, 10));}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
   $result[$i] =substr($array[$i], 11,);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are other answers:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d(.*)/', '$1', $array);
```

Or it could be shorter:

```
$result = preg_replace('[\d-]{10}(.*)/', '$1', $array);
```

Comment: You couldddd just use `\d{4}` andd `\d{2}`

Comment: @Rizier123: Yes ;-)  `array_column()` didnt work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Considering the first space in the string as delimiter:

```
foreach ($arr as &$v) {
    $v = substr($v, strpos($v, " "));
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  abc xyz
    [1] =>  ef yz
    [2] =>  ghij aei
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $new[] = explode(' ', $value, 2)[1];
}
```

Dereferencing the `explode` result requires PHP >= 5.4.